# how to ask userid, password as a input in shell script for FTP transfer

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

I am using the below script but I will use SecureID to login hence the user Id and Passwd is dynamic I need to enter each time in that case how can I change the below query?

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='sample.ftp.com'
USER='user'
PASSWD='pwd'
FILE='*SPHINMP1*'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
binary
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Cheers,
Hanish

Comment: So your question is not *"automate FTP in shell script"*, but *"how to ask user for input in shell script"*.

Comment: Hello Martin I will change the question

Comment: Martin can you help me how to use the above query without user id and password hardcoded since am using the RSA token to login.

Comment: Did you follow the link to the duplicate question?

Comment: but that seems different I have copied your code only but it works if I hardcode the user name and Password inside the script but we are not using the static password hence it is failed

Comment: Your comment does not make sense. Show us what did you try (append your new code to the question).

Comment: hello martin sorry for that am new to unix here is my expectation i need to make a FTP transfer from one server to another server so obviously it will ask for user ID and Password to connect the remote host in the above code the userID and Passwd is hardcoded in my case i should not hard code since it is based on the RSA token ID when ever i will run the script it should ask for password so i will enter my token to connect the server that is the issue

Comment: This this the error i got when i use  Login incorrect.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.

Comment: You keep repeating what you want to implement. We understand that! And I believe that the solution in the duplicate question, is what you are looking for. Unless you show us that it does not work for you, there's nothing I can add it.